# Diablo 2 Andariel in 30 seconds

Tags: diablo-ii, speedrun

I found [this Diablo 2 video](https://youtu.be/xPNrhgD8K3s) ("Andariel 1000 runs").

In the first seconds of the video, there is a sort of multiple steps teleport to reach and beat Andariel in about 30 seconds. In the rest of the video, there is a comment about the drops of the 1000 runs.

I suppose that the character has optimized high-level gear to beat it, but I do not understand how he can get to the boss so fast.

I have seen similar "quick teleport to boss" in other videos - can you explain to me how he can go so fast from base to the boss?

Of course, sorceress teleport (or armor with enigma) is involved, but from the video, it seems something like "waypoint, teleport, teleport, teleport, boss" and I do not understand the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no trick to it. On single player (non-battle.net play) the map is consistent. He simply reads the map and teleports to the icons on the map.

If you leave the game and start a new one *on the same difficulty*, your map history will be saved.

For example, if you go from Normal -> Nightmare, the map will be random and you'll have to find the correct way again.

Comment: I did not know that teleport worked on maps icons. (I played very few sorceress)

Comment: @Luca Teleport doesn't work on the maps icons ... The map always stays the same in Singleplayer and is always visible. You just know where to teleport. Another thing is that the people who plan to do videos like that reroll their map until its perfect for teleporting to the boss quickly. As I said the map stays the same, but if they join the game in another difficulty, the prior map gets lost. So they the repeat this process until they get a very good map with a short path to the boss.